# Redirect to HTTPS on IIS 7 for static files

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, https

One of the domains on my webserver is being used for serving static files. All sites I have found when talking about forcing SSL, talk about editing your web.config file. I don't have that for this site. How would I force all HTTP traffic to HTTPS? Do I create a web.config file with the code in the root of the site?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize it before, there is a web.config file on the root of the site. I added the required code and it works.

Comment: Thank you, works find with me,

Answer (score 1):

Just add web.config in folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and it works like @Mike Wills said